# If for iid, continuous, positive $X$ and $Y$ we have $X+Y=Z$, how is $\mathbb{E}(X\text{ }\textbf{1}_{\{Z\leq z\}})$ defined?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

I'm starting off with this line of working (which I am not sure is correct but I think this expectation is an integral with respect to $x$ only - correct me if I'm wrong?):

$\mathbb{E}(X\text{ }\textbf{1}_{\{Z\leq z\}})= \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_{X}(x)\textbf{1}_{\{Z\leq z\}}dx =\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_{X}(x)\textbf{1}_{\{X+Y\leq z\}}dx $

My next line of working is as follows (which I am again not confident in?):

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_{X}(x)\textbf{1}_{\{X+Y\leq z\}}dx =\int_{0}^{z-x}\int_{0}^{z} xf_{X}(x)f_Z(z)dx\text{ } dy $

My reasoning for the double integral is that we need $X+Y\leq z$ so we need to integrate w.r.t $x$ and $y$?  Is it also correct to multiply what's inside the integral by the PDF of $Z$?

Essentially have/where have I gone wrong with defining this expectation in integral form?

I'll appreciate any help from you.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula's are not correct. In your first equality LHS is a  number and RHS is a random variable since it involves $1_{Z \leq z}$.

Use the following: $EX1_{X+Y \leq z}=\int_0^{z}\int_0^{z-y}x f(x)f(y)dxdy$ where $f$ is the common density function (assuming the density exists).

Comment: Thank you. Can I also clarify then that $\mathbb{E}(f(Z)\text{ }\textbf{1}_{\{Z\leq z\}})=\int_0^zf(z)f_Z(z)dz$ for 'nice' $f$ and where $f_Z$ is the density of $Z$? Thanks.

Comment: @maths54321 Yes, that is correct.